# What rows acquire locks when doing a select query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

For a select query, for what rows are read locks acquired? Is it only the rows that match the filter, or all rows that had to be scanned?

Answer (score 1):

First, note that locks are only needed for read-write transactions but not for read-only transactions. (https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/reads)

Cloud Spanner will acquire locks on all the returned rows. It will also acquire enough extra locks to avoid “false negatives”, which are rows that aren’t returned because they initially don’t match the filter, but then are modified to match the filter before your transaction commits. These false negatives are often called “phantom rows:” you execute a query and get a set of a results, and then in the same transaction you execute the exact same query and get more rows. If the query plan does a scan over the base table, we will take a range lock on the whole table, so that no phantom rows can appear until your transaction completes. If the query plan uses an index to find rows with value ‘X’ for field ‘Y’, then we’ll lock a range of the index corresponding to all possible index entries for ‘Y=X’, so that if any transaction wants to insert a new index entry with ‘Y=X’ it would have to wait until your transaction completes.